# Azure Pipeline string curly braces

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipeline variable containing a string into which I wish to insert a JavaScript parameter.

```
PipelineVariable: 'http://url/${id}'
```

React function:

```
myUrl: id =>`#{PipelineVariable}`
```

Unfortunately it seems the curly braces in Pipeline variable are interpolated so the output of this function is:

```
http://url/$%7Bid%7D
```

Any suggestions for how to get round this, presumably by preventing escaping of the braces? I want to call myUrl('12345') and get

```
http://url/12345
```

The following does work, but I want to embed the id within the Azure string.

```
    myUrl: id =>`#{PipelineVariable}/${id}`
```

Comment: What's the task you're using?

Comment: Unfortunately I know too little about the Azure build process to answer your query, which may be part of the problem

Comment: Azure pipeline is a series of tasks either in a yaml file as code or through the visual guide. A pipeline could be either a build pipeline or a release pipeline. 

Wait, are you talking about Azure or Azure Devops?

Comment: Devops - just corrected tags

Comment: Have found what I believe is the list of tasks, but don't know which one does variable substitution in the build...

Comment: There's usually one of them that will have an option like 'variable substitution'. Also on the menu of Devops you'll find something called 'variables'. Click on each of the task and look at them. One of them must have tokens for variable substitutions with tokens '#{' and '}'

Comment: I have the list of variables, just cannot see a task obviously labelled which does the replacement

Comment: Okay, I've found a 'replace tokens' task in the release tasks; it doesn't seem to mention escaping curly braces though. The script seems to be https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task#readme

Comment: I was sure it was that. change the tokens that it uses to capture the variables to something that won't mess with your things. Something that won't need escaping basically. That should fix it

Comment: The variable capture tokens are #{ and }.This shouldn't interfere with ${ and }

Unfortunately as a new developer I don't have the ability to change a long standing project setup issue such as this, so I think I'm just going to have to pull the variable out of the replacement string

Comment: Yes, change them and then change your variable to the appropriate tokens. Just saw your post. It's up to you what you'll do but that's your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help

Comment: Unfortunately not a solution but at least I have a fair idea of why it's happening and can justify a less well coded workaround